# How to check application responding in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, dotnet, healthcheck

I am a newbie in k8s. I have a .net framework application written in C# running in K8s orchestration. I simply want to check in fixed interval (lets say in every 300sec) that my application which is running inside pod is responding or not.
Can anyone suggest how to implement this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kubernetes supports TCP, HTTP, and shell-exec [probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes) for an application startup, readiness, and liveness [health checks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/). If your application is a web application, you can use HTTP based liveness healthcheck as shown in the following code snippet:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-http
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/liveness
    args:
    - /server
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 8080
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 300
```